# Why can't I remove the [] in the "\caption[]{afsda\footnote{123}}"?

Tags: captions, footnotes, minipage

I search for a way to insert footnote in a caption and I do it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

 
 
  \begin{figure}[h]
  \begin{minipage}{0.5\textwidth}
  \centering
    \includegraphics[]{first.jpg}
        \caption[]{afsda\footnote{123}}
        \label{fig:fasdfa}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}         

\end{document}
```

It works alright. But when I delete the `[]` in the `\caption[]{afsda\footnote{123}}`, the Texwork shows an error:

```
LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.
Overfull \hbox (23.23076pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 11--12
 [][]
```

I always use `\caption{}`, but this time I can't.

Comment: Did you rerun it? Did the warning show the second time as well?

Comment: do you really want a footnote also in the list of figures? also do you want an empty text in the list of figures, which is what `[]` gives, I would expect `\caption[afsda]{afsda\footnote{123}}`

Comment: And that's not an error, just a warning which reminds you of changed label(s). 0 errors is usually the target, but 0 warnings (in LaTeX) is not always necessary.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Right, it is a warning. But tested second time, it has an error.

Comment: @Marijn Maybe my Texwork does not works well.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Maybe my Texwork does not works well

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I know now. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get errors from

```
\caption{afsda\footnote{123}}
```

because `\footnote` is a fragile command. But in this case adding `\protect` is not really useful.

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\textheight}{6cm} % just to produce a smaller picture

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\section{Test}

text

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\fbox{\LARGE Image}

\caption{Caption text\protect\footnote{Footnote text}}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Can you see what goes wrong? Yes, you get a footnote from the `\listoffigures` but ***not*** from the `figure`.

And if you change into

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\textheight}{6cm} % just to produce a smaller picture

\begin{document}

\listoffigures

\section{Test}

text

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\fbox{\LARGE Image}

\caption[Caption text]{Caption text\footnote{Footnote text}}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

you get ***no*** footnote.

[image]

Why? Because a `figure` is a float and a `\footnote` is another kind of float, but floats inside floats are not allowed. The footnote simply disappears.

OK, possibly LaTeX should warn about this disappearance, but it doesn't.

You might resort to

```
\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\fbox{\LARGE Image}

\caption[Caption text]{Caption text\footnotemark}

\end{figure}
\footnotetext{Footnote text}
```

but there would be no guarantee that the footnote text is typeset in the same page as the `figure`. And no, only specifying `[h]` would not solve the problem.

You need the optional argument to `\caption` because you of course don't want a footnote mark in the list of figures. But even if this worked, readers will be confused about what the footnote refers to.

Comment: Hello, before, I searched the way of adding `footnotemark` and `footnotetext`. But sometimes the footnote text is not on the same page as the `figure`. So, I try to solve this by adding a command `\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000` before the aommand `\begin{document}`, but it was no use. Then, I try to solve this by using `minipage`.

Comment: @Y.zeng Just don't footnote captions. Is it *really* useful?

Comment: But I need to insert footnotes in captions. And may you teach me why there must be `[]` in `caption[]{}`?

Comment: Is it `minipage` an possible way to do this?